# Tableau can't sum (10^10 numbers)

Tags: csv, int, sum, tableau-api

I've been doing some harmless operations, basically combining 2 ids to create a unique id, and as the ids are numbers, I decided to use math operations to combine then (rather then string concatenation). So, as my second id is alwas < 10000, what I did was id1*10000 + id2

Problem is, Tableau doesn't seem to know how to add those numbers. To illustrate better, I created Calculation 1 (that is Id1*10000), Calculation2 (that is Id2) and Calculation3 (that is Calculation1 + Calculation2).

Check the file. http://www.speedyshare.com/Wc5zP/Tableau-can-t-sum.twbx

Original datasource is a csv file, but it's extracted (to a tde).

One thing that might be happening is that Tableau has some limitation on the size of int it can store. Anyone knows how I can change this? (Int64 would do the trick, if that is actually the problem)

Here a snapshot

[image: Check this weird result]

Comment: Is there any special reason you don't want to use strings, other than just because? I'm on my mobile but I can check your twbx later.

Comment: No reason, just curiosity. In fact, I'm joining on both ids, so that's not even an issue at all. Just got curious about any possible Tableau limitation on int type, what would be a problem if I ever deal with large numbers

Comment: File no longer exists.  Knowing the Tableau version would be helpful.  Knowing the exact error message would be helpful.

Comment: Just edited the question with the new link. The problem was originally reproduced in 8.2, but just opened this twbx on 9.0 and the problem persists. No error messages, it's just adding wrong. Check the file.

Comment: Added a snapshot. Last column shoud be [Calculation1] + [Calculation2]